# How to implement basic loops in matlab workspace in python?

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

The following code:

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.eval('i=1;', nargout=0)
eng.eval('while i<10', nargout=0)
eng.eval('i=i+1', nargout=0)
eng.eval('end;', nargout=0)
eng.quit()
```

always shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "while.py", line 13, in <module>
  main()
File "while.py", line 7, in main
  eng.eval('while i<10', nargout=0)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py", line 84, in __call__
  _stderr, feval=True).result()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py", line 68, in result
  return self.__future.result(timeout)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py", line 82, in result
  self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
SyntaxError: Error: At least one END is missing: the statement may begin here.
```

as if the 'end;' statement is not executed in the Matlab workspace. Why? What is the solution ?

Comment: can you send is all as one line? `eng.eval('i=1\nwhile i<10\ni=i+1\nend;', nargout=0)` It's been far too long since I've worked with matlab to remember specifically how the shell interprets line continuation..

Comment: No dude. It is not going to work anyway because of `\n`. Also check my comment on L. Scott Johnson's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eval() needs to complete on its own. Try this (UNTESTED):

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.eval('i=1; while i<10; i=i+1; end', nargout=0)
eng.quit()
```

Comment: It does. But what if I want to print each value of i (using `i=i+1` only) successively? It turns out that `eng.eval('i=1; while i<10; i=i+1 end', nargout=0)` shows the following error `SyntaxError: Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword "end".`

Comment: Also, isn't there some proper documentation available on Matlab engine ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a semicolon before the "end"

Comment: To put multiple executable statements on one line in Matlab, you must separate them with a semi-colon `;`. If you want to print each value of `i` then don't do it using the "lazy" method of omitting the semi-colon, instead use disp...  `eng.eval('i=1; while i<10; i=i+1; disp(i); end;', nargout=0)`. The error in your comment is caused by an unexpected `end` statement on the same "line" as `i=i+1`